# SNMP GETBULK Issue: Only could get parts records(Such as 59 records, but there are more than 100 records)

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I would like to get the interface information for the router by snmp GETBULK, but when I use it, only parts of the record were returned.

The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
    snmp.listen();

    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
    target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
    target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
    target.setAddress(new UdpAddress("127.0.0.1/161"));
    target.setTimeout(3000);    //3s
    target.setRetries(1);

    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    pdu.setType(PDU.GETBULK);
    pdu.setMaxRepetitions(200); 
    pdu.setNonRepeaters(0);
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1"))); 

    ResponseEvent responseEvent = snmp.send(pdu, target);
    PDU response = responseEvent.getResponse();

    if (response == null) {
        System.out.println("TimeOut...");
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (response.getErrorStatus() == PDU.noError) 
        {
            Vector<? extends VariableBinding> vbs = response.getVariableBindings();
            for (VariableBinding vb : vbs) {
                System.out.println(vb + " ," + vb.getVariable().getSyntaxString());
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error:" + response.getErrorStatusText());
        }
    }
}
```

After executing it, there are 59 records be returned, but if I use GETNEXT to get them, there are about 197 records be returned.

Any ideas?

Hope anyone could help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How big are your responses? Remember - a getbulk response has to fit in a single UDP packet. That's an absolute limit of 65,535 bytes - or if you've got MTU limitations potentially as small as 1,500 bytes.

Comment: So what's the solution? How do you get back more data?

Comment: @darrickc break down your request into several separate requests. Or limit the maximum number of responses to your getbulk request.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, and can happen for a few reasons.

Quoting [RFC 3416 §4.2.3 "The GetBulkRequest-PDU"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#section-4.2.3) (emphasis mine):

> [..] The receiving SNMP entity produces a Response-PDU with **up to** the total number of requested variable bindings communicated by the request.
>
> [..] While the maximum number of variable bindings in the Response-PDU is    bounded by N + (M * R), the response may be generated with a lesser number of variable bindings (possibly zero) for either of three reasons.
>
> 1. If the size of the message encapsulating the Response-PDU
>    containing the requested number of variable bindings would be
>    greater than either a local constraint or the maximum message
>    size of the originator, then the response is generated with a
>    lesser number of variable bindings.  This lesser number is the
>    ordered set of variable bindings with some of the variable
>    bindings at the end of the set removed, such that the size of
>    the message encapsulating the Response-PDU is approximately
>    equal to but no greater than either a local constraint or the
>    maximum message size of the originator.  Note that the number
>    of variable bindings removed has no relationship to the values
>    of N, M, or R.
> 2. The response may also be generated with a lesser number of
>    variable bindings if for some value of iteration i, such that i
>    is greater than zero and less than or equal to M, that all of
>    the generated variable bindings have the value field set to
>    "endOfMibView".  In this case, the variable bindings may be
>    truncated after the (N + (i * R))-th variable binding.
> 3. In the event that the processing of a request with many
>    repetitions requires a significantly greater amount of
>    processing time than a normal request, then a command responder
>    application may terminate the request with less than the full
>    number of repetitions, providing at least one repetition is
>    completed.
>
> [..]

In your case, you're most likely exceeding the maximum message size.

If you get fewer objects than you wanted, you can just do another *GetBulk* request starting where you left off. (This is the same as how you handle TCP/IP sockets in C code — you have to keep `read()`ing in turn until you have everything you want.)

For example, implementations such as Net-SNMP's `snmptable` (a table walker that can be instructed to use *GetBulk*) will do this until the end of the table has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that the original poster had the solution : use GETNEXT instead of GETBULK and you will get all of the records. GETBULK will only work for you if your returns are within the size PP. specified.

Comment: This is only partially helpful. It is true that there is an upper bound on the amount of data returned, but if you're using GetBulk you're probably doing so for a reason: it's generally better to continue performing GetBulk requests for your remaining objects (as many as needed!) rather than drop your request down to just _one_ object at a time (efficient!).

Comment: Indeed, a GetNext is _also_ subject to these constraints if you plug enough varbinds into the request!